# Speech recognition for javascript node.js

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech

Currently, I'm working on a side project. I'm using javascript and node.js as of now. I'm trying to add voice recognition to my applications, although not in the browser. I know there's a lot of things out there that use the browser's speech recognition API, but I normally run my scripts in terminal using my mac. For example what I'm trying to achieve is something as follows.
I would say something, and if this corresponds with an if statement then the script will do whatever task as requested. So if I say "Hello" it will do whatever task that does when said.
Is there anything even like this?

Comment: You can find an answer to your question with various libraries, like [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-simple-voice-assistant-for-your-mac-in-python-62247543b626). I think this question is too broad though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of Node modules that just wrap the browser's speech recognition if available, which is no help if you aren't in a browser. There are also several modules that are interfaces to external services that will do speech recognition for you, if you send them the audio.

If you're looking for a module that actually does local speech recognition, instead of just farming out the problem to someone else, the only thing I could find was [pocketsphinx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pocketsphinx), which, while it is a wrapper for a tool that you have to have installed (i.e. the recognizer itself isn't in JavaScript), nonetheless purportedly allows you to do local, on-device speech recognition from NodeJS, without having to worry about "pricing" or privacy.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, how reliable is pocketsphinx? does it require a strong computer? Also, as backup plan how do I run something in the browser? Currently, I'm using a program called Atom, it allows me to write in javascript and HTML and I find it very efficient with node.js. How could I run the program in the browser? I understand how you run one script in the browser but not a whole folder of scripts or something. This might sound completely noobie because I am to this.

Comment: I've never actually used pocketsphinx, but given that it is free and produced by scientists it probably won't work as well out of the box as Google's commercial offering. It definitely won't work in the browser, because it wants to run compiled code on the computer it is running on.

In the browser there's the SpeechRecognition API, which browsers can provide, but currently only Chrome provides it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#Browser_compatibility

On other browsers you could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/speech-polyfill to provide that API.

Comment: Sounds like I'll just use a browser to skip all this hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Google has documentation for their speech API built for NodeJS [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech). It will allow you to upload a sound file, or open a channel to the API server. This will allow you to get a lot of data about what they said: duration, what they said in a text file, confidence and more. You can check out their API and pricing [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I don't have spare change so the google API wouldn't be a solution for me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sonus just seems to use google cloud API, and as far as I'm aware of google clouds speech recognition costs money.